# Need to filter by month

Tags: sql-server, database-design, select, full-text-search, where

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

I am trying to filter by month using dtm DATETIME as my format XX/XX/XXXX. I am very new to SQL, so I was trying to just filter by the month of January 01 with the format

```
... WHERE Date = '01/XX/XXXX'
```

is there a way to search by date like this?

```
SELECT TPolicies.intPolicyID       AS 'Policy ID',
       TPolicies.strPolicyNumber   AS 'Policy Number',
       TPolicies.dtmDateOfPurchase AS 'Purchase Date',
       TPolicyTypes.strPolicyType  AS 'Policy Type',
       TAgents.intAgentID          AS 'Agent ID',
       TAgents.strFirstName        AS 'Agent First Name',
       TAgents.strLastName         AS 'Agent Last Name'
FROM   TCustomerPolicies
       JOIN TCustomers
            ON  TCustomerPolicies.intCustomerID = TCustomers.intCustomerID
       JOIN TPolicies
            ON  TCustomerPolicies.intPolicyID = TPolicies.intPolicyID
       JOIN TStates
            ON  TCustomers.intStateID = TStates.intStateID
       JOIN TGenders
            ON  TCustomers.intGenderID = TGenders.intGenderID
       JOIN TRaces1
            ON  TCustomers.intRaceID = TRaces1.intRaceID
       JOIN TPolicyTypes
            ON  TPolicies.intPolicyTypeID = TPolicyTypes.intPolicyTypeID
       JOIN TAgents
            ON  TPolicies.intAgentID = TAgents.intAgentID
WHERE  TPolicies.dtmDateOfPurchase =
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott, if you update your question with more information (such as which database system you are using specifically, e.g. Microsoft SQL Server vs Oracle vs MySQL vs PostgreSQL, etc) then I'll adjust my example to be more specific to your case. (In general, it's best to include as much relevant information as possible when you ask a question here.)

Usually there is a built in function or way to parse out the month of a date in SQL. For Microsoft SQL Server for example, this would be the MONTH() function. An example of this as a filter is:

```
WHERE Date = MONTH('01/13/2020')
```

MONTH Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

In Oracle PL/SQL you can use the built in EXTRACT function. Here's an example:

```
WHERE Date = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2020-01-13')
```

EXTRACT Doc: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry for not being specific enough new to this, I am trying to extract data from specific sources, that are attached a specific month from a specific column

Comment: I figured it out, Thanks WHERE Month (TPolicies.dtmDateOfPurchase) = 5

Comment: @Roadkill No problem, glad to have been of help!